# How can I save draggable element position using Meteor?

Tags: meteor, draggable

I am trying to save draggable element position in Meteor collection, in order to be able to use drag and drop characteristics in a Meteor app, so different users can watch position changes in real time. Everytime I drag and drop an element it changes its position, but after refreshing the page it appears at the original spot. The item goes back to the save position if I touch it with the mouse a bit so....

How can I make the element going back to the saved position onRendered??

My project is https://github.com/dalareo/design-thinking

How can I save element position?

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: How can I save position?